# Каким способом или хитростью можно внедрить PHP в HTML

Tags: php, html

Я не специалист в области программирования, но интересы к данному роду деительности не дают мне оставить разработкy собственного ресурса. Разрабатываю дизайн сайта с помощью программы "Serif WebPlus X5".

Но есть одно "но" сайту нужна динамика, а где ее взять? Сможет ли мне помочь в данном вопросе программа "Adobe Dreamweaver CS"? Вообщем я жду помощи в этом вопросе ...

Comment: @MACJIO, Вы хотите заниматься web-разработкой в дальнейшем? Или Вам просто нужен сайт? Если разработкой - ниже Вам ответили. Если Вам нужен только 1 сайт, то не вижу смысла убивать время на изучение. Просто наймите программиста.

Comment: @Виталий Кустов зачем нанимать программиста если есть говноJoomla? =)

Comment: @Palmervan, если у человека свой дизайн, то кто-то должен будет его внедрить в ту же джумлу. В любом случае при такой постановке вопроса не вижу смысла самому во всем разбираться.

Comment: @Palmervan, :улыбка:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что можно сказать по этому вопросу, в 2005году у меня были похожие проблемы,тогда я только начинал работать в этом направлении, на тот момент никто не хотел мне помогать, программисты знающие язык php не охотно делились своими знаниями. И что я вижу?! Спустя семь лет картина остается почти такая же. С радостью тебе помогу обойти все те ошибки которые встречались у меня на пути.

Предлагаю мини вступление, а если станет интересно то продолжим.

1. Любой сайт состоит из гипертекстовой разметки (HTML)- это своего рода инструкция браузеру (opera, mozila и т.д.)  отобразить информацию в виде документа, в удобной для человека форме. На сегодняшний день самая свежая версия HTML 5. Ее  уже можно использовать но надо помнить,что она  еще находится в стадии разработки. Окончательный релиз запланирован на 2014 год.
2. Что бы сайт стал красивым и приятным для восприятия глаза человеческого были  разработаны каскадные таблицы стилей (CSS). С помощью стилей можно отдельно от общего кода работать с шрифтом, цветом, создавать конструкцию сайта в виде отдельных блоков и много другое... Свежей версией считается CSS3. Это все то, с чем ты работаешь сейчас используя программу "Serif WebPlus X5", она помогает тебе быстро создавать простые странички. Но без знаний вышеописанных основ далеко не уедешь, пусть даже программа у тебя будет супер-пупер навороченная (Dreamweaver например). Хочешь сэкономить время на обучении? Начинай с видео уроков!Ссылку тут не пиши во избежание непонимания админами (кому интересны мои находки пишите, дам ссылки).
3. Допустим ты изучил и написал красивый и приятный сайт. А вот чтобы сайт у тебя стал еще и умным, ему нужен динамический код(PHP,JavaScript).
    Научиться программировать можно даже сидя дома. Вот тебе маленький кодик который ты можешь засунуть в любую часть своего кода HTML  между тегами<body>  </body>

-

```
<?php echo "это просто супер";?>
```

Пока всё, если интересно, пиши, продолжим.

Comment: Не забывайте, что для работы этого самого PHP кода нужно ещё, чтобы это было запущено на сервере.

Comment: <?php
//   ##########################
 $thank_You ='Cпасибо';
 
 echo $thank_You . " !"; 
/*
:D?> ##########################
                       
*/

Answer (score 3):

Adobe Dreamweaver CS без знания языка бесполезен, лично я его использую исключительно для подсветки кода и устанения ошибок на стадии разработки.
Начинай с изучения html и css - понадобится для вёрстки страниц.
Далее изучи серверный язак php или какой другой, с его помощью ты сможешь генерировать html страницы, работать с базой данных, создавать файлы.....
Также рекомендую изучить какую-нибудь уже готовую систему для разработки сайтов(CSM). 
Если хочешь динамики на самой странице, то изучай ещё javascript и какой-нибудь фреймворк(самый распостранённый jQuery), чтоб не изобретать велосипед.
И наконец если хочешь получать информацию с сервера без перезагрузки изучай ajax(используется javascript).
Всё это проще учить по видеокусам которых в нете полно

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте, что такое вообще PHP: [тут](http://php.su/php/?php) (и остальные статьи там и не только).

Советую делать самому, и выбросить эти программы, если собираетесь всерьёз заняться.

Answer (score 0):

Лучшая программа для написания сайтов - **Блокнот**.
Учите **html**+**javascript**+**php** это проще чем разобраться во всяческих программах...

Comment: Не согласен с вами... Большинство программистов насколько мне известно используют Notepad++ для работы и подсветки кода. Тем более при работе из блокнота в PHP могут возникнуть всякого рода "сюрпризы". Классический пример -- Блокнот сохраняет Юникод только с BOM'ом, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: Есть очень удобные IDE для PHP. ИМХО, использование только Блокнота - не обязательно условие, чтобы быть супер-программистом.

Comment: А никто это и не пытался сказать. Но и обратное тоже не верно. А блокнот помогает учиться на своих ошибках.

Comment: ИМХО, для новичка лучше как минимум текстовый редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса (типа PSPad). Это ничуть не хуже помогает учиться.